# Gmail action buttons

Tags: gmail, formatting

Recently [Gmail](https://gmail.com) started showing "action" buttons next to emails that have links to trigger actions on certain third-party sites. For instance:

[image: Buttons]

At first, I only noticed it with emails from [Amazon](http://amazon.com), but it appears that emails from arbitrary sites occasionally have that, too.

How is Gmail able to tell?

This is so I can send emails that have such action buttons as well to my users (in case it's something special with the headers or such).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Schemas`, [here's](https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/) Google's documentation about it.

[And here's](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.se/2013/05/introducing-actions-in-inbox-powered-by.html) the blog-post with the introduction of it.